# Default value in asciidoctor include directive

Tags: include, default-value, asciidoctor

Is it possible to have a default value for an `include` directive?

Let's say I have a line like this in my `.adoc` file:

```
include::{snippets}/some-snippet.adoc[]
```

in case if the file `{snippets}/some-snippet.adoc` is not present, I want a default value to be displayed instead. Something like this comes to mind:

```
include::{snippets}/some-snippet.adoc[default='a snippet of something']
```

but I cannot find anything like it in the [docs](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-directive).

Comment: If includes are not found you should see some warnings. Aren't they enough for you?

Comment: That would be my way to avoid having the warnings there even if some includes have failed (;